# Changing Interleaving Rows in a Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a 12700 x 307 data frame with the following sort of genetic data: individual ID numbers in columns, locus identity in rows (note two rows for each locus)

```
alist<-c("loci",185,186,187,188,189,190,191,"A549",1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"A549",0,0,1,1,1,0,1,"A588",1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"A588",0,0,0,0,0,0,1,"A794",1,1,1,1,1,1,1,"A794",1,0,1,0,1,1,0,"A081",1,1,1,1,1,1,0,"A081",1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(alist), nrow=9, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(df) = df[1, ]
df<-df[-1, ]
```

I need to change it to a data frame with two rows for each individual, one column for each locus. The first row of individual should have the presence/absence entry for the 1st allele and the second row the 2nd allele for that locus.

So it should look like this:

```
blist<-c("individual","A549","A588","A794","A081","185",1,1,1,1,"185",0,0,1,1,"186",1,1,1,1,"186",0,0,0,1,"187",1,1,1,1,"187",1,0,1,1,"188",1,1,1,1,"188",1,0,0,1,"189",1,1,1,1,"189",1,0,1,1,"190",1,1,1,1,"190",0,0,1,1,"191",1,1,1,0,"191",1,1,0,1)
dfb <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(blist), nrow=15, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(dfb) = dfb[1, ]
dfb<-dfb[-1, ]
```

It must be quite do-able but I am not seeing it. I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this base R solution using various data management procedures. It is set up to scale to actual production data if you simply change the 8 in column number reference to full length column:

```
# TRANSPOSING DATA FRAME
tdf <- as.data.frame(t(df[,-1]))

# SETTING COLUMN NAMES
names(tdf) <- as.list(df$loci)    
# SETTING INDIVIDUAL COLUMN
tdf$individual <- rownames(tdf)

# STACK SAME COLUMNS (CHANGE 8 TO NUMBER OF COLS(307))
finaldf <- rbind(tdf[, c(ncol(tdf), seq(1, 8, 2))],   # EVEN COLS
                 tdf[, c(ncol(tdf), seq(2, 8, 2))])   # ODD COLS

# ORDER BY INDIVIDUAL COLUMN
finaldf <- finaldf[with(finaldf, order(individual)), ]
rownames(finaldf) <- 1:nrow(finaldf)

# CONVERT LOCI COLUMNS TO NUMERIC
finaldf[,-1] <- sapply(sapply(finaldf[,-1], as.character), as.numeric)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    individual  A549    A588    A794    A081
1         185      1       1       1       1
2         185      0       0       1       1
3         186      1       1       1       1
4         186      0       0       0       1
5         187      1       1       1       1
6         187      1       0       1       1
7         188      1       1       1       1
8         188      1       0       0       1
9         189      1       1       1       1
10        189      1       0       1       1
11        190      1       1       1       1
12        190      0       0       1       1
13        191      1       1       1       0
14        191      1       1       0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

It works by `gather`ing your data to long form.

Then it `group_by`s loci and individual, and `mutates` on a `row_number` as you have repeated ids.

Then it `spread`s back to long in the direction specified, and `select`s out the row column:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% gather(individual, val, -loci) %>%
       group_by(loci, individual) %>%
       mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
       spread(loci, val) %>%
       select(-row)

   individual  A081  A549  A588  A794
       (fctr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr)
1         185     1     1     1     1
2         185     1     0     0     1
3         186     1     1     1     1
4         186     1     0     0     0
5         187     1     1     1     1
6         187     1     1     0     1
7         188     1     1     1     1
8         188     1     1     0     0
9         189     1     1     1     1
10        189     1     1     0     1
11        190     1     1     1     1
12        190     1     0     0     1
13        191     0     1     1     1
14        191     1     1     1     0
```